# Merging and formating Excel Worksheets with power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying to format an excel file using Power Query in order to be able to pivot it, but I haven't been able to do it right.

I'm merging many worksheets from different workbooks into one. Every sheet has the data of the specific workbook in the first 3 rows (column 1= Title; and Column 2= Value), and then I have the table well formatted starting in row 5 (with headers and all, but different amount of rows each)

How can I transform the data in the first 3 rows of every sheet into columns, so I can get a Pivotable table?

Here an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWrl2.png) of what I get when merging 2 files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the picture I assume you would like to transform such kind of file

[image]

to something like that

[image]

I used the following M-Code for that

```
let
    Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents("D:\tmp\Files\file1.txt"), null, null, 1252)}),
    #"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(Source,3),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Kept First Rows", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(tab)", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Col1", "Col2"}),
    step = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Col1", type text}, {"Col2", type text}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(step),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    Hdr = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Nummer", type text}, {"Id", type text}}),
    Custom1 = Source,
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Custom1,4),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Top Rows", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(tab)", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}, {"Column1.4", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers1" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type1", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers1",{{"F1", Int64.Type}, {"F2", Int64.Type}, {"F3", Int64.Type}, {"F4", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Nummer", each Hdr[Nummer]),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "ID", each Hdr[Id]),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Export", each Hdr[Export]),
    #"Expanded Export" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Export"),
    #"Expanded ID" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Export", "ID"),
    #"Expanded Nummer" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded ID", "Nummer"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Nummer",{{"Export", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```